# ogr2ogr append to PostGIS table with PRIMARY KEY -fieldmap: Invalid destination field index 0

Tags: postgis, ogr2ogr

I have the following PostgreSQL/PostGIS table

```sql
CREATE TABLE schema.table 
(
    id   bigint    NOT NULL CONSTRAINT id_pkey PRIMARY KEY, 
    geog geography NOT NULL
);
```

and an `ARCGEN` file `file.gen` which I want to append to the above table.

```
1 11.3 58.3
11.3 58.4
11.4 58.3
11.3 58.2
11.2 58.2
11.1 58.3
11.3 58.4
END
2 -168.7 58.3
-168.7 58.2
-168.8 58.2
-168.9 58.3
-168.8 58.4
-168.6 58.3
-168.7 58.2
END
3 -168.8 58.5
-168.6 58.5
-168.8 58.4
-168.9 58.5
-168.9 58.6
-168.8 58.6
-168.6 58.6
-168.6 58.5
END
4 -168.8 58.8
-168.6 58.7
-168.8 58.7
-168.9 58.7
-168.9 58.8
-168.8 58.9
-168.6 58.8
-168.6 58.7
END
5 -168.8 59.0
-168.6 59.0
-168.8 58.9
-168.9 59.0
-168.9 59.1
-168.8 59.1
-168.6 59.1
-168.6 59.0
END
6 -168.8 59.3
-168.6 59.2
-168.8 59.2
-168.9 59.2
-168.9 59.3
-168.8 59.4
-168.6 59.3
-168.6 59.2
END
7 -168.8 59.5
-168.6 59.5
-168.8 59.4
-168.9 59.5
-168.9 59.6
-168.8 59.6
-168.6 59.6
-168.6 59.5
END
8 -168.8 59.8
-168.6 59.7
-168.8 59.7
-168.9 59.7
-168.9 59.8
-168.8 59.9
-168.6 59.8
-168.6 59.7
END
9 -168.8 60.0
-168.6 60.0
-168.8 59.9
-168.9 60.0
-168.9 60.1
-168.8 60.1
-168.6 60.1
-168.6 60.0
END
10 -168.8 60.3
-168.6 60.2
-168.8 60.2
-168.9 60.2
-168.9 60.3
-168.8 60.4
-168.6 60.3
-168.6 60.2
END
END
```

To do this I use the following command:

```
ogr2ogr --config PG_USE_COPY YES   \
         -nln      schema.table    \
         -update                   \
         -append                   \
         -fieldmap identity        \
         -f        "PostgreSQL"    \
         PG:"host=192.168.56.1 port=5432 dbname=dev01 user=admin password=password"                 \
         ~/output/file.gen
```

However, I get the error `ERROR 1: Invalid destination field index 0.`

I know that this has something to do with the `-fieldmap` option. Both, the source and destination, have 2 columns, so I tried `identity`, `0,1`, and other options like `-1,identity,1`, `identity,2`... Because I had no luck with that, and just to be sure, I tried to convert the `ARCGEN` file into `GEOJSON` and `SHAPEFILE`, but that resulted in the same error.

If I remove the `CONSTRAINT id_pkey PRIMARY KEY` from my destination table, the data from the `ARCGEN` file is successfully copied to the PostGIS table.

Answer (score 0):

The source .gen dataset is composed by 1 field only (of geometry type), while the destination table has two fields, with types: 0: integer, 1:geometry.

So what you need to do is to send your unique input field in the destination field 1.
This can be achieved by using:

> -fieldmap 0

When you use "identity" it is required that source and destination have matching fields, same number and same order.